# Ввод данных в эксель

Tags: excel

Предположим, в Excel ввожу данные, например номера телефона.

Какую ввести функцию, которая при вводе уже существующего номера будет сообщать об ошибке, или просто в соседнем столбце сообщать об этом?

Comment: @Аваз Бенджамин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
=СЧЕТЕСЛИ(диапазон;новый_номер)>0

=ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСКПОЗ(новый_номер;диапазон;))
```

*ИСТИНА* - есть такой номер.

Можно к ячейкам, в которые вводятся номера, применить инструмент *Проверка_данных* (закладка *Данные*), использовав похожую формулу.

Если на листе, можно добавить проверку:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЕТЕСЛИ(диапазон;новый_номер);"уже есть";"порядок")
```

Answer (score 1):

Я делал по-другому в Microsoft Office 2007.

Выделял весь столбец, даже незаполненные строки. 
Потом на вкладке "Главная" выбирал - "Условное форматирование".
Далее выбирал - "Правила выделения ячеек".
Далее - "Повторяющиеся значения".
Далее выбрал как выделять и нажимаю ОК.
Вот и все, все повторы будут выделены цветом.